# qmlimportscanner not accossiated with a Qt version

Tags: linux, qt, qml

I need to run qmlimportscanner. I tried the one which was already installed in /usr/bin/importscanner on Linux mint 18. It gives me this:

```
qmlimportscanner: could not find a Qt installation of ''
```

I installed qt5-default and qtbase5-dev via sudo apt-get.. but same thing. Then I tried to run with qtchooser like this:

```
qtchooser -run-tool=qmlimportscanner -qt=5
```

which give me this:

```
 qtchooser: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmlimportscanner': No such file or directory
```

I tried to copy /usr/bin/importscanner to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/ but then it returns nothing and gets stuck..

What is wrong? I started a virtual machine with a fresh new linux mint 18 and initially /usr/bin/importscanner was there and exactly the same story.. What is wrong?

Comment: Still gives qtchooser: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin//usr/bin/qmlimportscanner': No such file or directory.

Comment: Try with: `qtchooser /usr/bin/importscanner -qt=5`

Comment: It does not work

Answer (score 2):

I God Damn solved it! I had to install qtdeclarative5-dev-tools as well.. But how can one know? If google weren't there, how could I've solved it?

Comment: You can always just download Qt and install it.

Comment: Yeah, what is apt-get for anyway?

Comment: With apt-file it would be possible. When you execute this command `apt-file search qmlimportscanner` you get this as a result:  
`qt6-declarative-dev-tools: /usr/lib/qt6/libexec/qmlimportscanner`  
`qtchooser: /usr/bin/qmlimportscanner`  
`qtdeclarative5-dev-tools: /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmlimportscanner`  
`qtdeclarative5-dev-tools: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmlimportscanner`